# Global variable attribution in promise function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I tried to insert function toDataurl in an Angular project that lets us to convert assets picture into base64 string.

```
toDataURL(url) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (extract) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var fr = new FileReader();
      var test = fr.onload = function() {
        extract(this.result);
        return this.result;
      };
      fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); // async call
    };
    xhr.send(); 
  });
  return promise;
}
```

I tried to assaign its result to the global variable `base64result` in the `promise` function. But this variable behaves like a local variable. I need it for next instructions.

```
this.toDataURL(chemin).then((result) => {
  this.base64result=result
});
```

Thank you

Comment: global scripts should be declared in your `angular.json` file. Have you done that ?

Comment: No. what i should write there?

Comment: You should provide tour js file in the `scripts` array